# Threejs object with multiple material doesn't work with RayCasting

Tags: three.js, 3d

I have created a 3d object using blender and exported it as .obj file.

I am trying to load that .obj file using OBJloader in threejs. That is a single object with multiple material in it. It is loaded without any issues.

I am trying to track which material the user has clicked in a 3d object. I am using raycasting for this. Since raycasting works only at object level, I am not able to get which specific material user has clicked.

Comment: I've made a PR to make this task easier: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15613. If it gets merged, you can evaluate `intersection.face.materialIndex` and then retrieve the correct material from your materials array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with `three.js R101`, you can evaluate `intersection.face.materialIndex` and then retrieve the correct material from your materials array. This was actually a missing feature in previous `three.js` revisions.